# How can I convexify (allowed some approximation) the objective function?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, disciplined-convex-programming

I have a known matrix, $H$ of size $U\times B$.
The optimization variable is $D$ of same size, which is binary

Now I have $$S_u=\frac{\sum\limits_{b=1}^{B} D_{u,b}H_{u,b}}{\sum\limits_{b=1}^{B}H_{u,b}-\sum\limits_{b=1}^{B} D_{u,b}H_{u,b}},\quad \forall u\in\{1,\cdots, U\}$$ and I want to maximize $\sum\limits_{u=1}^US_u$.

UPDATE:

with $b_\min\le \sum_{b=1}^B D_{u,b}\le b_\max, \forall u$ and $\sum_{u=1}^{U}D_{u,b}\le u_\max, \forall b$

Can I perform some alternative formulation so that the function becomes convex, or any convex approximation?

EDIT:

The denominator is strictly non-negative. The first or positive part of the denominator denotes the case where $D_{u,b}=1, \forall b, b=1,\cdots, B$

Also, the elements in $H$ are non-negative.

Comment: Do you have any other constraints?  If not, you can solve a separate problem for each $u$.

Comment: For EDIT-2, you should not mix $\sum_u$ and $\forall u$.

Comment: @RobPratt, yes, I have other constraints. The constraints are on $D$. Please see my update.

Comment: @RobPratt, how can I enforce the equality constraint? does it make much sense to add an equality constraint in optimization?

Comment: In your new denominator, you have $\sum_u$ when the ratio itself depends on $u$. Should the sum instead be over a dummy index $v$ or just omitted?

Comment: @RobPratt, I have corrected it here https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5289/how-can-i-formulate-an-lp-or-heuristic-solution-for-this-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reformulate exactly as a MILP problem by performing a Charnes-Cooper transformation and then a linearization of the resulting products of binary and continuous variables, as described in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500493/doing-a-charnes-cooper-transformation-with-matrices-and-an-zero-one-constraint/3500608?r=SearchResults#3500608).

Because you have a sum of ratios here, introduce a new variable $T_u$ for each summand $S_u$.  The idea is to multiply numerator and denominator by $T_u$ so that the denominator becomes 1.  You want to maximize $$\sum_{u,b} D_{u,b} H_{u,b} T_u$$ subject to $$\sum_b H_{u,b} T_u - \sum_b D_{u,b} H_{u,b} T_u = 1$$ for each $u$.  Now introduce $Y_{u,b} = T_u\cdot D_{u,b}$ to linearize both objective and constraint:
$$\text{maximize $\sum_{u,b} H_{u,b} Y_{u,b}$ subject to $\sum_b H_{u,b} T_u - \sum_b H_{u,b} Y_{u,b}=1$}$$
Finally, linearize the relationship between $Y$ and $D$.

---

For your new question in EDIT 2, first linearize $P_{u,b}D_{u,b}$ and then apply Charnes-Cooper.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. would you please elaborate a bit. That mean I should introduce additional variable!

Comment: Can you provide the details of how this is done when the objective is the sum of linear fractionals, as it is in this case? And of course, the transformation is dependent on the nonnegativty of the denominator, which the OP did not state.holds, so should be added as an assunption in the solution..

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, I state that the denominator is nonnegative. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I added more detail.  You just need a separate multiplier for each ratio.

Comment: @RobPratt, thanks for your answer. I am now implementing it. In fact, I posted a simplified version of my problem. In my original problem, I have another variable, $P_{u,b}$. How can I deal with it? See my EDIT-2.

Comment: @RobPratt, I suppose, for linearization, you are thinking of big M approach. What should be an ideal value for $M$ in this case?

Comment: Yes, when linearizing a product of binary and continuous, the upper bound on the continuous variable is a reasonable value for big M.

Comment: @RobPratt, for EDIT-2, the second linearization will be for the product of two continuous variables, right?

Comment: @RobPratt, how can I model the equality constraint. If I put this as $\le 1$, I can solve, but the objective value is 1, If I put it as $==1$, I get infeasible solution.